# mongoosejs how to sort a distinct query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

How to sort a distinct query
I tried this

```
exports.categories = function(req, res) {
    Article.distinct({'categories' : true}).sort({'categories': 1}).exec(function(err, categories) {
        if (err) {
           return res.json(500,{ error: 'Cannot get the categories' });
        }
        res.json(categories); 
    });
};
```

but it doesn't work.

### UPDATE

For the reply of @Neil Lunn

```
exports.categories = function(req, res) {
    Article.aggregate(
    [
        { '$group': { '_id': '$categories' }},
        { '$sort': { 'categories': 1 }}
    ])
    .exec(function(err,categories) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json(500, err);
        } 
        res.json(categories);
    });
};
```

but I've got like

> [{"_id":["Primi"]},{"_id":["Primi","Secondi"]},{"_id":["Dolci"]},{"_id":["Secondi"]}]

Comment: Should have left me a comment. Lucky I saw this, but there is an edit and I probably should have asked you if these were actually arrays. They usually are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not `.sort()` because it does not return a cursor. The `.distinct()` method is sort of a wrapper around mapReduce and not the same as the results from a `.find()` command which does return a cursor.

So even better than this use the aggregation framework instead:

```
Article.aggregate(
    [
        { "$unwind": "$categories" },
        { "$group": { "_id": "$categories" },
        { "$sort": { "categories": 1 }
    ],
    function(err,result) {

       // work here
    }
);
```

The output is a little different but the overall result should be a bit faster and sorted.

You could also have just used the JavaScript `.sort()` method on the array that is returned as the response from the distinct method, and just as you can use the JavaScript `.map()` method to strip the "values" from the `_id` keys in the objects of the aggregate result.

Still say the `.aggregate()` method should work better than `.distinct()` since the implementation on the server is native code and not JavaScript and interpreted.